# `git subtree pull` yields weird change list in main project?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-subtree

I use `dai-client-matcher` as a `subtree` in a main project. I recently made a small commit to `dai-client-matcher` and tried to `git subtree pull`, as what I have always done so far, to the main project. The pulling & merging process seemed to go well until I manually checked each commit and found that the merging commit was saying that I had done a lot of changes (including lots of deletions) in my main project.

Here is two last commits in `dai-client-matcher`:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, in the last commit I only made a single change in one single file namely `src/dcm_refdb_mnger.hpp`.

Current status of the main project:

[image]

The second line from the bottom shows the last merge of `dai-client-matcher` (commit `5e822365`) to the main project.

Now I `git subtree pull` the last commit of `dai-client-matcher` to the main project:

```
duong2179-mbpro:main-project duong2179$ git fetch dai-client-matcher test-subtree
From git.abc.xyz.com:dai-client-matcher
 * branch              test-subtree -> FETCH_HEAD
duong2179-mbpro:main-project duong2179$ git subtree pull --prefix subtrees/dai-client-matcher dai-client-matcher test-subtree --squash
From git.abc.xyz.com:dai-client-matcher
 * branch              test-subtree -> FETCH_HEAD
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 subtrees/dai-client-matcher/src/dcm_refdb_mnger.hpp | 1 -
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
```

Things seem to go well until I manually check the merge commit in the main project:

[image]

The right side shows that I have done a lot of changes to the code base of main project.

Have I done anything wrong here? Why does the merge commit show a lot of changes like this?